# Theme not working on the spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-theme

I am not able to understand why the Spinner TextColor and style is not changing When I applied the custom styles to application theme. Also the background of the Spinner List in the popup is not changing. If I apply the theme to the spinner with android:theme attribute then the list text becomes bold.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     ....
     ....
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

**Spinner**

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/accent"
                    android:entries="@array/trans_type"/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        .....
        .....
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

**Java Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome, " + userDetails.get(D.USER.COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME));

    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    ......
    ......
 }
```

Comment: show your java code

Comment: @Ironman I have added the java code. But there is nothing related to spinner adapter in code except for getting its values. Spinner instance is retrieved using Butterknife library.

Comment: @Vishal in your layout i can see you are not applying the style so that's why `AppCompactSpinner` is not taking the style.